# cap production deploy ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano3

I tried to deploy the ruby on rails project from a github folder. However, I got such an error when I run `cap production deploy`

```
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in 
'require': cannot load such file -- capistrano/cli (LoadError) from /home/deploy/.rbenv/
versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in 'require' 
from /usr/bin/cap:3:in '<main>'
```

I have deploy.rb starting with:

```
# config valid only for Capistrano 3.1
lock '3.1.0'
```

And I installed Capistrano v.3.1 with the following command-line:

```
gem install capistrano -v 3.1.0
```

Anybody has ideas why I still got an error?

Attached Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '4.1.0'
# Frontend
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'nested_form', github: 'ryanb/nested_form'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.2.0'
gem 'kaminari'

# Javascript
gem 'gon'
gem 'angularjs-rails'
gem 'selectize-rails'
gem 'js-routes'

# Backend
gem 'pg'
gem 'mongoid', github: 'mongoid/mongoid'
gem 'mongoid_geospatial'
gem "active_model_serializers"
gem 'devise'
gem 'state_machine'
gem "rolify"
gem "pundit"
gem 'enumerize'
gem 'simple-rss'
gem 'tweetstream'
gem 'swagger-docs', path: "vendor/gems/swagger-docs-0.1.5"
gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary'
gem 'wicked_pdf'
gem 'paper_trail', '~> 3.0.3'

# Temporary
gem 'faker'
gem 'factory_girl_rails'

# Asset gems
gem 'haml-rails'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
gem 'compass-rails'

group :development do
  gem 'spring' # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'switch_user'
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'binding_of_caller'
  gem 'sextant'
  gem 'guard-livereload', require: false
  gem 'capistrano', '~> 3.1.0'
  gem 'capistrano-bundler', '~> 1.1.2'
  gem 'capistrano-rails', '~> 1.1.1'
  gem 'capistrano-rbenv', github: "capistrano/rbenv"
end

group :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'spring-commands-rspec'
  gem 'guard-rspec'
  gem 'fuubar'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'capybara-webkit'
  gem 'capybara-email'
  gem 'capybara-screenshot'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
end

group :test, :darwin do
 gem 'rb-fsevent'# if `uname` =~ /Darwin/
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'pry-rails'
  gem 'pry-remote'
end
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you install capistrano by adding capistrano to the GEMFILE.
And then run the bundle install command.
And then run bundle exec cap install. to Generate config files.
Then do the configuration as per appropriate per your project. 

Could you show also your Gemfile. So we can try figure out what is causting this issue here.

You could try follow the instructions from https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano and start from the beginning and see if the same issue still there.

Comment: @ChawlaS , thanks for the quick reply. I have add the Gemfile.